# Каким образом jQuery вычисляет token?

Tags: jquery, сеть, token

Каким образом jQuery вычисляет token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь правильно понял вопрос. Если посмотреть [исходник](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js), то буквально в первых строчках можно увидеть переменную `ajax_nonce`:

```
ajax_nonce = jQuery.now()
```

`jQuery.now()` возвращает количество миллисекунд прошедших с 1970/01/01.

Затем, при каждом запросе `ajax_nonce` увеличивается на 1, тем самым создавая токен для следующего запроса.

Comment: @Павел Азанов, есть сайт, у котороо token почему-то совпадает с PHPSESS. Ведь такого быть не должно, верно?

Comment: @ололо, интересно, можно ссылку?